# Pandas series being read as dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
    cut     value1  value2  distance    
0   1961.0  0.0     0.0     0   
1   1961.0  0.0     1.0     0.812976 
2   1962.0  0.0     2.0     0.78076     
3   1962.0  0.0     3.0     0.907385    
4   1963.0  0.0     4.0     0.49206     
5   1963.0  0.0     5.0     0.751321 
6   1963.0  0.0     6.0     0.566744
```

I wanted to group by `cut`, using `df.groupby('cut').max()` but got the following error:

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'cut' not 1-dimensional
```

I realized it's because the series is being read as a dataframe:

```
In: type(df)
Out: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In: type(df['cut'])
Out: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Why is this happening?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of when I try to output the series:

[image]

Comment: Wait what... did you accidentally use `df[['cut']]` instead of `df['cut']`?

Comment: Nope. I'll post a screenshot too.

Comment: How did you create this dataframe?  I can't reproduce your error using this with pd.read_clipboard(), which makes me suspect there's something weird earlier in your code.

Comment: @A.Leistra probably should have found this myself, but your comment made me go back and check. my columns were accidentally created using `columns = [['cut', 'value1'...]]` rather than `['cut', 'value1'...]`. Surprised it didn't throw an error, and that this was the result. Will post solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the columns in the dataframe were in an extra tuple, like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [['cut', 'value1', 'value2', 'distance']])
```

when they should have been:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['cut', 'value1', 'value2', 'distance'])
```